# Explaining an environmental variable by OTU abundance

Tags: r, environment-variables, correlation

I'm currently stuck on R. 
I need to explain an environmental variable (gas flux) with microbial OTU abundances. 
What I have is my abundance table with stations in rows and otus in columns. And I also have my environmental variables table with stations in rows and gas fluxes in columns.
I have already made constraints analysis such as CCA, but I would like to see which OTU correlates with the gas fluxes and obtain a p.value. To do so, I have been trying with the lm() function but it fails!

To be honest, I never had to do this, and am not even sure that I am doing the right test.
Why is it not working ? Should I use another test?

See the code below :

````
> summary(lm)

Call:
lm(formula = ocs_flux ~ . - soil, data = a_genus_bar)

Residuals:
ALL 24 residuals are 0: no residual degrees of freedom!

Coefficients: (428 not defined because of singularities)
                      Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)          1.0888175         NA      NA       NA
Pseudochloris       -0.0393109         NA      NA       NA
Entransia            0.0404868         NA      NA       NA
Targionia                   NA         NA      NA       NA
Prototheca                  NA         NA      NA       NA
Aureococcus                 NA         NA      NA       NA
Lophocolea                  NA         NA      NA       NA
Nyholmiella          1.4399916         NA      NA       NA
Nowellia                    NA         NA      NA       NA
Euhalothece                 NA         NA      NA       NA
Dicranum            -1.3496055         NA      NA       NA
Takakia              0.0367361         NA      NA       NA
Microchaete         -0.6997106         NA      NA       NA
Weymouthia                  NA         NA      NA       NA
Odontella                   NA         NA      NA       NA
Chroomonas           0.3009968         NA      NA       NA
Phormidium                  NA         NA      NA       NA
Mnium                0.0106978         NA      NA       NA
Strombomonas                NA         NA      NA       NA
Auxenochlorella     -0.0925440         NA      NA       NA
Gracilariopsis              NA         NA      NA       NA
Wildemania                  NA         NA      NA       NA
Nephroselmis                NA         NA      NA       NA
Pseudanabaena               NA         NA      NA       NA
Prochloron                  NA         NA      NA       NA
 [ getOption("max.print") est atteint -- 202 lignes omises ]

Residual standard error: NaN on 0 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:      1, Adjusted R-squared:    NaN 
F-statistic:   NaN on 23 and 0 DF,  p-value: NA```
````

Comment: Differential abundance analysis is difficult. I would recommend you read up on some of the commonly used techniques before you start your analysis.  To more directly answer your question, your current test isn't working because you have 24 observations and more than 200 explanatory variables.  Linear regression won't work if the number of observations is fewer than the number of explanatory variables.

Comment: you can just correlate the abundance with gas_flux first? I suspect you end up with NAs because a lot of them are either all zeros or correlated